# List of files not accessed for the last 1 year in shared folder using powershell

Tags: powershell, file, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

I am trying to get a list of files in shared folder not accessed for more than one year , i gave the filter AddMonths(-12) also tried AddYears(-1) , doesnt work, list generated in csv contains file having date as current year

```
$time = Get-Date
$time.AddMonths(-12)

get-childitem "\\Ajay-1\" -Recurse -File -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue| Where- 
Object {$_.LastAccessTime -lt $time} | select fullname,lastaccesstime |
export-csv "D:\Time\Last.csv" -notypeinfo
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd have better luck modifying how you're handling `$time`

```
$time = (Get-Date).AddDays(-365)
$path = "C:\"

Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse -Force  | Where-Object {$_.LastAccessTime -lt $time} | select fullname,lastaccesstime |export-csv "D:\Time\Last.csv" -notypeinfo
```

Using this should achieve what you're looking for.